# prevent blank pages from being counted

Tags: page-numbering, blank-page

How can I prevent blank pages from being counted?
In the MWE below I would prefer to number the page with "Some notes" as page 2.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
First page
\clearpage\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
Some notes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a good idea. By convention, all pages of a book are counted, leading  to odd- numbered pages on the right and even-numbered pages on the left (in left-to-right languages). Anything else is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You'll confuse your readers who expect even numbered pages on the left.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcounter{blankpages}
\newcommand{\makeblankpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}%
  \stepcounter{blankpages}%
  \clearpage
}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\the\numexpr\value{page}-\value{blankpages}\relax}%

\begin{document}

First page

\makeblankpage

\vspace*{\fill} % just to make a smaller picture

Some notes

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use different numbering schemese, the redefinition of `\thepage` should go when you switch to arabic numbers.